# Validate one list item is present in another list

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I've got a model that looks like this:

```cs
public class ValidationModel
{
    public List<string> ValidNames;
    public List<Child> Children;
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
```

I'm trying to write a fluent validator that will validate the `ValidationModel` class, and iterate around each child object in the `Children` collection and check to see if that value is present in the `ValidationModel` `ValidNames` collection.

```cs
public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<ValidationModel>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(o => o.Children).ChildRules(row =>
        {
            row.RuleFor(o => o.Name).IsPresentInValidNames()
        });
    }
}
```

How can I access the `ValidNames` collection in a rule shaped like the above? I basically want to do a contains on the `ValidNames` for each child in the `Children` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a `ChildValidator` with a constructor expecting a `validNames` array. With the help of *System.Linq* library, use `IEnumerable<T>.Contains(T)` to validate that the `Name` must be existed in the `validNames` array.

```cs
using System.Linq;

public class ChildValidator : AbstractValidator<Child>
{
    public ChildValidator(List<string> validNames)
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.Name)
            .Must(x => validNames.Contains(x))
            .WithMessage("Name does not exist in ValidNames");
    }
}
```

2. After `RuleForEach(o => o.Children)`, set the validator instance `new ChildValidator(x.ValidNames)` by passing the `ValidNames` array via `SetValidator()`.

```cs
public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<ValidationModel>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(o => o.Children)
            .SetValidator(x => new ChildValidator(x.ValidNames));
    }
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DMxKHq)